# Evil mode "o" auto indent in text mode - how to turn it off?

Tags: evil, indentation, electric-indent

When I press <kbd>o</kbd> in evil mode (which moves the cursor to the line under, and goes into insert mode), the cursor is indented by two spaces.

```
When I press o, the cursor goes
  here
```

This happens in `text mode` and `elisp` buffers.

I tried to shut it off with this:

```lisp
(defun remove-autoindent ()
  (electric-indent-mode nil))
 
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'remove-autoindent)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'remove-autoindent)
```

But it didn't work. Which setting is causing this behavior?

I do not have any indent instructions outside of `web-mode` `:config` within `use-package`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Are you using some starter configuration like doom or spacemacs? (this behavior does not occur when starting from `emacs -q`, at least not in text-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I just figured out a fix before finding this issue:

```
(setq evil-auto-indent nil)
```

Note however that if `evil-auto-indent` is set, pressing `o` just calls `indent-according-to-mode` behind the scenes, so however you have *that* set up is likely the root cause.